# get name of <a> which submitted form

Tags: jquery, forms, spring-mvc

I submit form using event `a onclick`

```
$("ul > li > a").click(function() {
    $("#redirectForm").submit();
});
```

My form looks like this

```
<form action="redirect.html" method="post" role="form" id="redirectForm">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" name="mainpage"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Главная</a>
        <li><a href="#" name="mainpage"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> События</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Участники</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="userloginlist"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Администратор</a>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Buy how to get the name of `a` which submitted form to server in my controller?

```
@RequestMapping("/redirect.html")
public String redirect(@RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams,
        Model model) {
    logger.debug("attempt to redirect");
    String next_page = allRequestParams.get("name");

    logger.debug("Parameter page: " + next_page);
    return "redirect: " + next_page;
}
```

The value of `next_page` is always null

Comment: don't know if it's a typo or not, but your 1st and fth `li` are missing the closing tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it thanks to `$(this).attr("name")` inside your click listener

```
$("ul > li > a").click(function() {
  var input = $("<input>")
           .attr("type", "hidden")
           .attr("name", "mydata").val($(this).attr("name"));
  $("#redirectForm").append($(input));
  $("#redirectForm").submit();
});
```

You can then access in your controller the param `name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You should add a hidden HTML field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="my_a_tag" value=""/>
```

And change your JS to this:

```
$("ul > li > a").click(function() {
    $("#my_a_tag").prop("value", $(this).prop("name"));
    $("#redirectForm").submit();
});
```

This will set the hidden field's value to the name of the clicked `a` tag. Then you can handle it in your server side code like any other form field.